# Issue to refresh in angular app when choosing same menu again

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, components

Description:

I'm encountering an issue in my Angular application where, upon clicking the menu within a component, the component does not refresh or reload. I would like to ensure that the component is reloaded when the menu for that specific component is clicked.

Problem Details:

When navigating to the same component and selecting the menu, the component does not refresh automatically. I'm seeking guidance on how to force a reload of the current component when its menu is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onSameUrlNavigation](https://angular.io/api/router/OnSameUrlNavigation) when define your routes

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
  })],
```

OR using standalone component

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(APP_ROUTES,withRouterConfig({
      onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
    })),
    ...
  ]
}
```

NOTE: If is the same component but different "arguments" subscribe in ngOnInit to ActivateRouter.Params, like show the [doc](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#params)